# My webswerver works fine when there is only 1 servo used/defined in my code

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I am trying to make a webserver which controls my 3 servos for a robotic arm. When I define and use 1 servo it is nice and quick, but whereas if I use more than 1 the webserver is very slow and barely loads. Someone please help.

I will post the code below. With this code the webserver is very slow:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Servo.h>
String readString;
Servo robotservo1;
Servo robotservo2;


byte mac[] = { 0x2C, 0xF7, 0xF1, 0x08, 0x29, 0xAF };
byte ip []={10,1,1,121};// check back of your shield
   // when the shield connected the serioal monitor will display the ip address
EthernetServer server(80); 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
 Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());// prints my IP address, so you can copy paste in browsr

robotservo1.attach(9);
robotservo2.attach(10);

robotservo1.write(45);
robotservo2.write(45);


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
EthernetClient client = server.available();
if (client) {
if (client.connected()){
  if (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  if (readString.length() < 100) {
          readString += c;
        } 
  if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.println(readString);                      
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();
          client.println("<hmtl>");
          client.println("<head>");
client.println("<title>Ethernet shield, hopefully works</title>");
client.println("</head>");
client.println("<title>");
client.println("Control the robotic arm using the buttons below");
client.println("</title>");
client.println("<body bgcolor = black>");
client.println("<font color = antiquewhite>");
client.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"4\">"); 
client.println("<b>");
client.println("Control the robotic arm by pressing the buttons below!!!");
client.println("</b>");
client.println("<body>");
client.println("<p>");
client.println("Servo 1 or Base");
client.println("<br>");
client.println("<FORM>");   
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv0\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv45\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv90\'>");
client.println("</FORM>");
client.println("</p>");

client.println("<p>");
client.println("Servo 2 or Elbow");
client.println("<br>");
client.println("<FORM>");   
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv0\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv45\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv90\'>");
client.println("</FORM>");
client.println("</p>");

client.println("<p>");
client.println("Servo 3 or Shoulder");
client.println("<br>");
client.println("<FORM>");   
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv0\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv45\'>");
client.println("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv90\'>");
client.println("</FORM>");
client.println("</p>");

client.println("</font>");
client.println("</body>");
client.println("</html>");

 delay(1);

  if(readString.indexOf("?baseserv0") >0)
            {
              robotservo1.write(0);
            }

          else{
            if(readString.indexOf("?baseserv45") >0)
            {
              robotservo1.write(45);
            }

          else{
            if(readString.indexOf("?baseserv90") >0)
            {
              robotservo1.write(90);
            }


  }

}


  if(readString.indexOf("?baseserv0") >0)
            {
              robotservo2.write(0);
            }

          else{
            if(readString.indexOf("?elbowserv45") >0)
            {
              robotservo2.write(45);
            }

          else{
            if(readString.indexOf("?elbowserv90") >0)
            {
              robotservo2.write(90);
            }


  }

}

  readString="";
          client.stop();      
  }}}}}
```

Comment: you code is hard to read because it is formatted badly ... please correct the indentation ... for instance, all of the `if` statements should be indented to the same level ... also, the `client.println()` should all be equally indented

Comment: stop the client before handling motors. and some reading https://github.com/jandrassy/StreamLib/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I have no Ethernet board so I couldn't test the timings, but when I compiled your code for an Uno, I got a low free-memory warning; that 83% of memory was used and stability problems could occur. That's the compiler telling you that your code might not run right. It may very well be the reason your server was slow. The largest user of data-memory (SRAM) is the text in your client.print() statements.

I put that text into program-memory (Flash, of which there is over 10x as much!) which got the SRAM use down to 29%! Try running that and see if it won't behave a little bit better:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Servo.h>
String readString;
Servo robotservo1;
Servo robotservo2;


byte mac[] = { 0x2C, 0xF7, 0xF1, 0x08, 0x29, 0xAF };
byte ip [] = {10, 1, 1, 121}; // check back of your shield
// when the shield connected the serioal monitor will display the ip address
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
   server.begin();
   Serial.print("server is at ");
   Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());// prints my IP address, so you can copy paste in browsr

   robotservo1.attach(9);
   robotservo2.attach(10);

   robotservo1.write(45);
   robotservo2.write(45);


}

void loop() {
   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   EthernetClient client = server.available();
   if (client) {
      if (client.connected()) {
         if (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            if (readString.length() < 100) {
               readString += c;
            }
            if (c == '\n') {
               Serial.println(readString);
               client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
               client.println(F("Content-Type: text/html"));
               client.println();
               client.println(F("<hmtl>"));
               client.println(F("<head>"));
               client.println(F("<title>Ethernet shield, hopefully works</title>"));
               client.println(F("</head>"));
               client.println(F("<title>"));
               client.println(F("Control the robotic arm using the buttons below"));
               client.println(F("</title>"));
               client.println(F("<body bgcolor = black>"));
               client.println(F("<font color = antiquewhite>"));
               client.println(F("<meta http-equiv=\")refresh\" content=\"4\">"));
               client.println(F("<b>"));
               client.println(F("Control the robotic arm by pressing the buttons below!!!"));
               client.println(F("</b>"));
               client.println(F("<body>"));
               client.println(F("<p>"));
               client.println(F("Servo 1 or Base"));
               client.println(F("<br>"));
               client.println(F("<FORM>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv0\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv45\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?baseserv90\'>"));
               client.println(F("</FORM>"));
               client.println(F("</p>"));

               client.println(F("<p>"));
               client.println(F("Servo 2 or Elbow"));
               client.println(F("<br>"));
               client.println(F("<FORM>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv0\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv45\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?elbowserv90\'>"));
               client.println(F("</FORM>"));
               client.println(F("</p>"));

               client.println(F("<p>"));
               client.println(F("Servo 3 or Shoulder"));
               client.println(F("<br>"));
               client.println(F("<FORM>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-0 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv0\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-45 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv45\'>"));
               client.println(F("<INPUT type=button value=Servo-90 onClick=window.location='/?shoulderserv90\'>"));
               client.println(F("</FORM>"));
               client.println(F("</p>"));

               client.println(F("</font>"));
               client.println(F("</body>"));
               client.println(F("</html>"));

               delay(1);

               if (readString.indexOf("?baseserv0") > 0)
               {
                  robotservo1.write(0);
               }

               else {
                  if (readString.indexOf("?baseserv45") > 0)
                  {
                     robotservo1.write(45);
                  }

                  else {
                     if (readString.indexOf("?baseserv90") > 0)
                     {
                        robotservo1.write(90);
                     }


                  }

               }


               if (readString.indexOf("?baseserv0") > 0)
               {
                  robotservo2.write(0);
               }

               else {
                  if (readString.indexOf("?elbowserv45") > 0)
                  {
                     robotservo2.write(45);
                  }

                  else {
                     if (readString.indexOf("?elbowserv90") > 0)
                     {
                        robotservo2.write(90);
                     }


                  }

               }

               readString = "";
               client.stop();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```